# How to get the list of facebook groups using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-group

I want the list of groups in which I'm member. In the Graph Api Explorer I did not find any permission like `user_groups`.
I select all the "User Data Permissions" and "Extended Permissions" but it did not work.

In graph api explorer I am using this command `GET->/v2.4/me/groups`.
and i get empty JSON data Like this.

```
{
  "data":[
  ]
}
```

And if I use the old graph api version 2.2 Like `GET->/v2.2/me/groups` then I get the groups only in which I am admin not all the groups.

If anyone have this experience and also have any solution please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Did you find a way around to get the list of all groups that you/users are a member of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: `user_groups` is deprecated with v2.4, see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

> the `user_groups` permission has been deprecated. Developers may continue to use the `user_managed_groups` permission to access the groups a person is the administrator of. This information is still accessed via the `/v2.4/{user_id}/groups` edge which is still available in v2.4.

Comment: but when i try to access via '/v2.4/{user_id}/groups' edge. it give me blank JSON data.

Comment: is there any way to access the list of user groups via facebook api's ?

Comment: I'm talking about the Graph API, so I don't understand your second comment. It's gone, and it's all in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Friend i got it. user_gorups permission is working great in Graph api v2.3.

Comment: actually you need to change the api version first and then re-access the permissions by clicking on get token button then you will fine the user_gorups permission there.

Comment: You can only change the Graph API version if your app supports it. If you'd create an app today, you wouldn't be able to use v2.3, just v2.4

Comment: Thanks for this additional knowledge. i created my app one year ago and now i start developing it.

Comment: Ok, that explains why it works... Have an additional look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog to see how long v2.3 will live.

Comment: i never read these type of information  but now because of you i understand it's importance.

Answer (score 4):

What are you looking for exactly?

1. The list of all groups that you are a member of?
2. The list of all groups that you admin?

I am not sure about A but at the time of writing this answer, Graph API v2.5 is the latest version and you can find the list of all the groups where you are the admin by using the admined_groups endpoint. You need the permission user_managed_groups in your Access Token, without the permission you will get empty data.

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/admined_groups/) is a link to the endpoint

Comment: As of today (April 2019) you can retrieve all Groups you are admin of from the Facebook Graph API by adding the "admin_only" to your query string.
Here is the link to the Facebook API documentation:
[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups)

Answer (score 1):

Update 27 Juli 2022

You must have permission called **groups_access_member_info** for get list group

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the list of Facebook groups, you can submit a request to the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/{ID GROUP}?&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```